# Points of $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, gaussian-integers

When $n = 2$, the points of $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$  are the vertices of a regular tiling of $\mathbb{C}$ by unit squares. When $n = 4$, the points of $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$ are the vertices of a tiling of $\mathbb{C}$ by right triangles. When $n = 3, 6$, the points of $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$ are the vertices of a tiling of $\mathbb{C}$ by equilateral triangles. (NB: I'm not even sure that these remarks are correct. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

What about when $n \neq 2,3,4,6$? My guess would be that when $n = 2^m 3^k$ for some $m,k \in \mathbb{N}$, we still get a discrete set of points (what tiling would the points correspond to?). I would also guess that when $n \neq 2^m 3^k$ for some $m,k \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Are these guesses right? If not, what actually happens?

## Edit

See the comments below this post. I made some mistakes in the first paragraph.

Comment: $n=2$ gives $\mathbb{Z}[e^{\pi i}]=\mathbb{Z}[-1]=\mathbb{Z}$ itself, not squares.  For $n\neq2,3,4,6$, $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, e.g., $1,i,\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{12}]$.

Comment: my bad. You're right. I was thinking of $n = 2$ as $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $n = 4$ as $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\pi/4}]$. In that case, it seems like there is at least one more $n$ that produces a regular tiling, namely $n =  8$, which does in fact correspond to $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\pi/4}]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim**: For $n\neq 1,2,3,4,6$, the cylotomic integers $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ (usual topology), where $\zeta_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

*Proof*: Note that, $2\cos(2\pi/n)-1=\zeta_n+\zeta_n^{n-1}-1\in\mathbb{R}^\times$, with absolute value $<1$ for these $n$.  Combining with the rotation $\zeta_n\notin\mathbb{R}$ then yields the desired result.

Comment: Could you explain this answer further? I'm not sure how this shows density. Even if you get density in $\mathbb{R}^x$ and apply the $n$ distinct rotations furnished by $\zeta_n$, you don't get density in $\mathbb{C}$, you only get density on the union of $n$ lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: An additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense iff it accumulates at $0$.  Since $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\cap\mathbb{R}$ is a ring and contains an element of absolute value $\in(0,1)$, taking high enough powers get you arbitrarily close to $0$.  So $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\cap\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.  Now use $\{1,\zeta\}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}$ and do the components separately.

Comment: I think I see. We can show there is some dense subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ contained in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$. Then $A \oplus A\zeta_n$, which must also be contained $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, is dense in $\mathbb{C}$. Edit: I posted this just as you made your last post. That makes sense. Thank you. I'll mark this as an answer.